# Dividing the sum of values of one column by count of all rows in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

Had a simple question, I am trying to get a rate or % by dividing the sum of one column ( Values ) by all the rows in that df.

```
   DF:

    ID | Values
     D      1
     B      0
     R      1
etc...
```

I want to take the sum of Values column an divide by count or number of rows inn the df.

Tryin something like

```
df[(df.Values.sum()] / len(df.ID)
```

Not sure if I am on right track

thanks!

Comment: `df['Values'].sum() / df.shape[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Use `mean`:

```
df['Values'].mean()
```

Output:

```
0.66666666666
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this answer and the `sum / len` answer will differ when there are NaN values in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Scott's method is stellar and I would do the same as him. However, correcting your code would be:

```
df['values'].sum() / len(df)
```